# CakePHP 2.0 detecting request type is behaving oddly

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Take a look at this code:

```
   if ($this->request->is('post')){
        $this->request->data['Profile']['userId'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if ($this->Profile->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->Profile->setPermissions($this->Profile->id, $this->request->data['Permission']);
            $this->NFSSession->setSuccessMessage('Your profile has been updated.');
        }else{
            $this->NFSSession->setSuccessMessage('There was a problem updating your profile.  Please try again.');
        }
    }else{
        echo 'Not a post request!!?!?!?!?!';
        debug($this->request->data);
    }
```

When I submit the form in the corresponding view for this action, it appears that $this->request->is('post') returns false.  The other end of the if/else statement is run.  Here's the weird bit - the POST data is there, and my call to debug($this->request->data) spits out the data I am expecting!

Here's the data that gets passed:

```
Array
(
[Profile] => Array
    (
        [aboutMe] => Hey there
    )

[Permission] => Array
    (
        [Profile] => Array
            (
                [aboutMe] => 1
            )

    )

)
```

Now, I could of course just change $this->request->is('post') to !empty($this->request->data) but that would not be grappling the problem head on.

So is anything wrong with my code?  What's going on?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your view look like? And specifically the form you're submitting.

Comment: It produces the POST data described above - surely that's the only relevant information about the view (apologies if I'm missing something)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using this:

`if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put'))`

http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2353

Comment: Thanks. I thought of trying this, but my form action is set to "post". Cake must see that I am updating something. The HTTP standard request type for updating is PUT.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a form in CakePHP, FormHelper::create() will use the info in $this->request->data to detect if your form is an add form or update form. If your model primary key is in your data, a hidden input field is generated to override the default HTTP method. This happens because probably you will update something.

```
<form id="RecipeEditForm" method="post" action="/recipes/edit/5">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
    ...
</form>
```

To check if your form was submitted when you create or update something, you can pass an array to CakeRequest::is() this way:

```
if($this->request->is(array('post','put')) {
    //...
}
```

More info: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-forms

[cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp)[cakephp-2.0](/questions/tagged/cakephp-2.0)

Comment: Hey there. Please explain *why* it is that he could also try this, and how it would solve the problem. We want quality answers on Stack Overflow, and this is somewhat overlooked here.

Comment: Hi, I updated my answer with more info and the source.